# Mount external ext4 with changed uid and gid

Tags: mount, permissions, fstab, ext4

I'm trying to share a single external hard-drive between two ubuntu different machines. The problem is, my user uid and gids are different across the two machines.

Is there a mount option for ext4 or ext3 that allows you to temporarily change your uid or gid?

Is my only option to have uniform uids across all my computers?

Answer (score 2):

> The simplest thing would be to ensure both default gids exist on both
> machines, and your uid is in both groups.

The simplest thing is to have one group in both machine with the same gid and use
something like

```
chmod 2770 YOUR_DRIVE
```

Where 2 is a setgid, that way any file created will inherit group permissions and you will be able to create or modify files on both systems using the same user who doesn't match it's uid.
If you want to create the group use

```
sudo groupadd --gid UNUSUSED_GID_HERE YOUR_GROUP_NAME
```

Do that on both machines, then chgrp to group name your drive.

Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

`mount` can't change UIDs on file systems that support unix-style file permissions, like ext3 and ext4.

It seems you can use [bindfs](http://bindfs.org/) (package `bindfs` on Ubuntu) to do that (but I never used it). It requires you to mount your external hard-drive a second time and will likely reduce performance.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root access to at least one of the machines, you can add or modify the uids and gids to make them match.

The simplest thing would be to ensure both default gids exist on both machines, and your uid is in both groups.

Example with an overly simple passwd and group listing.

```
Machine A:
userA: 1003: group_defaultA
group_defaultA: 1002: userA
group_defaultB: 1003: userA

Machine B: 
userB: 1005: group_defaultB
group_defaultB: 1003: userB
group_defaultA: 1002: userB
```